# Powershell v1: Is it possible to assign the result of a switch statement to a variable?

Tags: powershell, switch-statement

Is it possible to assign the result of a switch statement to a variable.

For example, instead of:

```
switch ($Extension) 
    { 
        doc {$Location = "C:\Users\username\Documents\"; break} 
        exe {$Location = "C:\Users\username\Downloads\"; break}
        default {$Location = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\"}
    }
```

Is it possible to do something similar to:

```
$Location = 
{
    switch ($Extension) 
    { 
        doc {"C:\Users\username\Documents\"; break} 
        exe {"C:\Users\username\Downloads\"; break}
        default {"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"}
    }
}
```

Trying the above results in $location containing the entire code block as a String.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For V1, I would wrap the switch statement in a function.

```
function Get-DocumentLocation($Extension)
{
    switch ($Extension) 
    { 
        doc {"C:\Users\username\Documents\"; break} 
        exe {"C:\Users\username\Downloads\"; break}
        default {"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"}
    }
}

$Location = Get-DocumentLocation $extension
```

Comment: Also, the original code gets a string of the code because you create a ScriptBlock ({switch()...}), but you don't invoke it:  &{switch()...}

Answer (score 2):

Does the following work?

```
$Location = (switch ($Extension) {
               doc {"C:\Users\username\Documents\"; break}
               exe {"C:\Users\username\Downloads\"; break}
               default {"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"}
             })
```

Or maybe

```
$Location = $(switch ($Extension) {
               doc {"C:\Users\username\Documents\"; break}
               exe {"C:\Users\username\Downloads\"; break}
               default {"C:\Users\username\Desktop\"}
             })
```

Don't have v1 here to test, right now but I think that might work.

Comment: Aren't your two choices the same?